# PHP value1/value2/value3/ to array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have a string like this: value1/value2/value3/ how can I get it into an array?

```
$array = "value1/value2/value3/"
echo($array[0]); // returns value1
```

? please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode`:

```
$array = explode('/', "value1/value2/value3");
echo $array[0];
```

Comment: Then mark his solution as the answer :)